# Remove all .cab .rip .guide .to

Tags: onion-routing

> I was wondering if anyone can explain to me on how to remove all of ?>the .to and .cab and .rip or .guide and so on and only keep .onion >only nothing else add to it. I look everywhere on this and I can't >seem to find anything that can help me in anyway. I'm running Windows >10 and I'm using wamp for onion hiddenservice so any help that would >be awesome. Thank you for your time.
>   Basiclly from what i have seen is that there is two onion Vs onion proxy and I need to figure out how to remove onion proxy. This way my server will only display my site without any extension at the end of onion. One person on here ask to see this then if it helps then here it is:

# Virtual Hosts  
# VirtualHost *:80 
 
  VirtualHost *:80 
  ServerName localhost 
  ServerAlias localhost 
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www" 
   Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/" 
   # Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
     Options -Indexes 
    AllowOverride None 
    Require local 
  /Directory 
/VirtualHost 

VirtualHost *:80 
  ServerName  npbsspajdfuxe7oq.onion 
  ServerAlias  npbsspajdfuxe7oq.onion 
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www" 
  Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/" 
    #Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
    Options -Indexes 
    AllowOverride None 
    Require local 
  /Directory 
  /VirtualHost

> Any help or link that show me how to do this would be awesome and I hope I said this more clear for ya. Which i have no idea how first time I said it wasn't clear but that's beyond me, anyway Thanks for your time and any help you can or have giving me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need your onion address to be "pingable", i.e. add it to your `SYSTEM32\drivers\etc\hosts` file a binding to 127.0.0.1 for your onion address. like changing:

```
 > 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

to

```
 > 127.0.0.1 localhost myhiddenservice.onion
```

so pinging like `ping myhiddenservice.onion` will ping 127.0.0.1 in cmd.exe window. After that just start your webserver bound to 127.0.0.1 and expecting a hostname `myhiddenservice.onion` in a `Host:` HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.0 header, and that's it!

For HTTP/1.0 case you need - if you need to work around **such an old stuff** that's rarely occured - you're using 127.0.0.2 IP address instead of 127.0.0.1 - the whole 127.x.x.x addresses are already pre-assigned to your PC, try pinging it ;) so bind the webserver to the IP address as a "default" host for it, i.e. use "IP-based virtual hosts".

Comment: This is garbled non-sense. How does this relate to the question?

Comment: as far as I can understand the question, he needs to know how to host on WAMP local hidden services and has a problem resolving dot-onion addresses to bind a webserver to it.

Comment: I think if you're not sure what the question is actually saying, you should ask the user to clarify it instead of just making up an answer to a question that you're not even sure i the user asked...and then to answer your made up question with bad information and wild and misleading statements. Not helpful.

Comment: well, for me the question was understood exactly as I said - so I've answered it. Nothing unclear, just the questions rephrased "in a simple words"

Comment: What i'm saying is when you go to my onion site you can view it like this .onion.link or onion.to or onion.guide and so on I want to know how to remove all of that and only keep .onion so other words when you get on my site and click .onion.link then it won't work because it been remove, so that's what I want to do is remove all .link and so on but no info on it.

Comment: what is your webserver virtualhosts config - can you attach it to the question? Looks like a binding bug in there - we'll fix it, don't worry!

Comment: From doing more research I found that there is two types : onion Vs onion proxy and onion proxy from what I understand has onion.link, onion.cab and so on but onion don't so how can I remove onion proxy so I can have only onion without any dot extension add on it?  my webserver is wamp  and yeah I can add it.

Comment: add it please, so my answer will be more precise

Comment: Here is the problem: two lines `ServerName localhost` and `ServerAlias localhost`. Try doing as I has answered. with these two lines on board Apache will never serve a pure dot-onion names. You don't need ServerAlias for an onion host, just use `ServerName xxxx.onion`. Forget about HTTP/1.0 case for now - let's test HTTP/1.1

Comment: I have done all of that and it still didn't remove .cab or .link or .rip ; for example,  npbsspajdfuxe7oq.onion.link  still can be view from what I read it's onion proxy How can I remove onion proxy so no matter what none of those extension won't work and you will have to use npbsspajdfuxe7oq.onion only without extension and as soon someone use extension on it like .link then it won't work. How can I make that happen? how can I remove onion proxy from my server? any help would be awesome and thank you for your help so far...

Comment: Guy from tor name : Donncha Ó Cearbhaill said if you block http requests which include a x-tor2web http header or you could set a robots.txt file So this problem is solved then so thank you @AlexeyVesnin for your help.

Comment: well, blocking tor2web is kind of useless, because you can set up a proxy of your own without any headers, so it will be technically impossible to determine the proxy requests among the others. So if your dot-onion service is available through Tor - it can be available through proxies, no problem to that fact. If you need wider darknet reach - add i2p gateway as well

Comment: Oh dam that sucks, ok Thank you for being so helpful I'm going mark your answer as good for being so helpful Thanks once again.